# Creating Select programatically within a form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grails

I make an ajax request to repopulate a select. The response is html code for creating a select. I do this to replace the select.

```
$("#search-dialog-form select").html(myNewSelect);
```

When I call `$("#search-dialog-form select option").length` I get the old value. I don't know the event but it does actualize the list, but I don't know exactly when. The select is in a form for a jquery-ui dialog.

I wanna fire force a refresh of the form or to adress the new select object to get its new length of its own options.

Any hints? Thanks in regards.

Comment: use event delegation

Comment: A listener on list which listenes to increase of options. Is that possible?

Comment: its called 2 way databinding

Comment: Sry... Question can be closed. It's due to the asynchronous ajax request, why I got the old value. Thank you though.

Comment: see my first comment :)

Comment: I put my check for empty list check in the succes part of the response of the request... It's ok thank you very much though...